# How to use a union using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, union

I have two tables:

1) Customer Table
2) Custmer Email Table

[image]
[image]

what i want to get both email ids which have customerId=4.
can I make a union and get my desire result like:
**

```
cusromerId:4
EmailId: sumit.printzone@gmail.com
         vinod.printzone@gmail.com
```

**

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Answer (score 1):

In lambda syntax this is what you want:

```
var emails = firstTable
    .Where(row => row.Id == 4)
    .Select(row => row.Email)
    .Union(secondTable
        .Where(row => row.Id == 4)    
        .Select(row => row.Email));
```